# Delete a user's file after some days after the user is deleted in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

In my Django application, I want to delete a user's media file(their profile picture and other images) after 4-5 days when the user deletes its account.

```
def delete_files(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    path = str(os.getcwd())
    try:
        pathdl = f"{path}\\data\\media\\{instance.username}"
        shutil.rmtree(pathdl)
    except Exception:
        print(Exception)


post_delete.connect(delete_files, sender=User)
```

I used `post_delete` to delete the files of the user, but how can I delete the file after 4-5 days or a certain time period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be good  to use django-celery-beat for periodical tasks:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-custom-schedulers

Use this as an example

Consider this as your users `models.py`. What you would need here is an expiration field that will be checked by the cronjob before deleting it.

`models.py`

```
   class Foo(models.model):
       UserId= models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True) #user pk here
       expiration_date = models.DateTimeField() # you would set the time here
```

`views.py`

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def add_foo(instance):
    # Create an instance of foo with expiration date now + one day
    objects.create(expiration_date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
        path = str(os.getcwd())
    try:
        pathdl = f"{path}\\data\\media\\{instance.username}"
        shutil.rmtree(pathdl)
        User.objects.create(expiration_date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
    except Exception:
        print(Exception)
post_delete.connect(delete_files, sender=User)
```

`tasks.py`

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from django.utils import timezone

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='*/5'))
def delete_old_foos():
    # Query all the expired date in our database
    userMedia = Users.objects.all()
    #Or get a specific user id to delete their file
    # Iterate through them
    for file in userMedia :
    
        # If the expiration date is bigger than now delete it
        if file.expiration_date < timezone.now():
            file.delete()
            # log deletion
    return "completed deleting file at {}".format(timezone.now())
```

You may also of-course incorporate this idea into any way you want to solve this problem.